# Use Pivoted / Filtered Data as the basis for a Report?

Tags: tableau

I have a worksheet in Tableau that is organized into rows and columns and filtered on an aggregate calculation just the way I want it. I'd like to make a report based on this workbook's results but I need it to show more fields than those in my worksheet. The problem is that if I add more fields to the "Rows" section, it changes the groupings and my filter based on the aggregation calculation doesn't give the same results anymore. Is there a way for me to use the filtered results on a worksheet to pull in only the rows from my dataset that are not filtered out in my worksheet?

Answer (score 1):

In Excel, pivot tables are both a fantastic way to immediately summarise data. Pivot tables have a secret function that can help you save a lot of time. For every unique item in such a field, the Display Report Filter Pages option duplicates an existing pivot table. Choose the pivot table and reports that you just want to copy. Use the Show Reports Filter Pages option to display the results of your report filtering.

The final outcome is still a worksheet with such a pivot table filtered for every item in this collection. The spreadsheet would be modified to correspond to the item name. Display Report Filters Pages are insensitive to changes to the original table format. All present pivot table filtering would be implemented across all new pivot tables. Before executing the filtering sheets, remove all other filters from those other fields, row, and columns.

Answer (score 1):

Tableau will work best for you when you feed it raw data. What you're doing is like taking a half-baked dish to Tableau and asking it to sort out, list, and change the ingredients without knowing what they are!

Take the data you're pivoting in Excel, and pivot it in Tableau instead. This will allow the aggregates to update dynamically alongside the filters.

In general, pivoting things in Tableau is as easy as in Excel -- Drag your measures out and choose aggregates appropriately. Once you have your aggregate calculations built, you can filter by the calculation results instead of the "static, flat excel" results.